# Using Apache's mod_auth across multiple sub-domains for single sign-on?

Tags: apache, authentication, single-sign-on, mod-auth

I have a domain and a group of sub-domains that require authentication to access. I am currently using mod_auth to authenticate users (mod_auth basic) at the domain.tld level. My goal is for single sign-on between the domain and all the sub-domains.

Will these credentials carry on to the sub-domains automatically, or with a simple vhost config change, or is there a better method to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### mod_auth_basic

Browsers distinguish areas that require HTTP authentication by a combination of the URL root and the name of the authentication realm.

Take for example, two domains each with a realm with the same name:

```
http://one.example.com/ with the realm "Please enter credentials!"
http://two.example.com/ with the realm "Please enter credentials!"
```

First a user visits `one`, is asked for credentials and enters them. Then the user visits `two`, the browser recognizes that the URL is different and thus asks again the user for her credentials.

This is a good thing, because otherwise www.badguy.com could set it up so that your browser sends over your online banking login.

In short: there is **no way to solve your problem with basic HTTP authentication** and standard HTTP clients.

### mod_auth_digest

You could use mod_auth_digest instead, since with that you can specify more than one URI to be in the same "protection space". However, with this authentication method there are two new problems:

1. It doesn't scale very well, because you cannot use wildcard domains.
2. Browser compatibility is not as good. (See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html#msie) on how to make it work with IE.)

Comment: Thanks for the response hop. I enabled the <a href='http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html">mod_auth_digest</a> module in Apache and configured the domain and it's sub-domains to use the same auth file.

It works in IE, but not Firefox.

Any other suggestions?